# Multilingual doc support for Clojure

Tags: clojure, documentation, multilingual

Is there any kind of multilingual documentation support for functions? I am from Turkey. I want people to write in Clojure and I dream a line like

```
(doc hello-world "Turkish")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of today there's no such feature built into the language. You can attach arbitrary metadata to vars, though:

```
(defn ^{:docs {:en "Prints and returns its argument"
               :es "Imprime y devuelve su argumento"}}
  debug [x]
  (println x)
  x)
```

Recall that Clojure's documentation system uses the `:doc` metadata keyword name. So you'd have to pick another name (e.g. `:docs`).

Then you could redefine functions such as `clojure.repl/doc` so they take into account your metadata.